# Stopping apache attack

Tags: apache-2.2

Since a few days my apache webserver is under attack. I get multiple requests to non-existant pages from multiple IP's. Is there anything I can do to stop it besides shutting down my apache server?

Currently I have closed port 80 to stop the logs filling up. Here is a part of my error.log:

```
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:55 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/view.aspx, referer: http://www.gamesfox.info/
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:55 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] script '/var/www/login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.wi8357.com/login.php
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:55 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/addyn, referer: http://www.dodomains.net
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:55 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/st, referer: http://www.addictedpeople.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:56 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/toindex1.asp, referer: http://98.126.93.27/toindex1.asp
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:56 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/st, referer: http://www.zopm.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:56 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/st, referer: http://www.zopm.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:56 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] script '/var/www/xml.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:56 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/config
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:57 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/addyn, referer: http://www.hypeshot.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:57 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/toindex1.asp, referer: http://98.126.93.27/toindex1.asp
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:57 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/addyn, referer: http://www.gkkv.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:57 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/st, referer: http://www.iyens.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:57 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/st, referer: http://www.titist.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:57 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/st, referer: http://www.yfia.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:58 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/addyn, referer: http://www.abundancegames.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:58 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/st, referer: http://www.chiefwork.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:58 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/pp, referer: http://www.thirdgames.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:58 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/toindex1.asp, referer: http://98.126.93.27/toindex1.asp
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:58 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/st, referer: http://www.newbiegamer.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:58 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/st, referer: http://luxuryup.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:59 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/st, referer: http://www.monopolyfreegame.com
[Tue Aug 16 17:12:59 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /var/www/pp, referer: http://luxuryup.com/
[Tue Aug 16 17:13:02 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] script '/var/www/login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.wi8357.com/login.php
[Tue Aug 16 17:13:02 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] script '/var/www/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://www.fire35.com
```

They are all different IP's, so my brute-force protection in iptables does not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is no attack but [referrer spamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spam).

Comment: so any way to stop this 'spamming' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was googling around, and found this :

http://mediakey.dk/~cc/block-referer-spam/

It seems there is a special module for apache2 to prevent referrer spam.

or

A more manual method with iptables :

http://www.iospirit.com/blog/article/12/Linux-HowTo-Defeating-referer-spam/

Answer (score 4):

If you want your server public there will be no way to stop it completely, but what you can do is use mod_evasive to intelligently block hosts making too many requests and/or mod security to match patterns and block hosts based on patterns.

Likely these will go away eventually

Comment: Any public webserver will be hit by waves of crap requests. The way to stop this is to not have your server publicly accessible.  Barring that my best additional advice is not to obsessively read your webserver logs -- Look at them when you need to troubleshoot something.

Comment: use logwatch and scan for odd patterns, and yes - 'agree' don't obsess over it or you will be tweaking for hours every day

Comment: logwatch or something similar is a great tool, but be wary of a low signal-to-noise ratio (or missing legit attacks) if not configured properly.  Getting real value from log watch is hit-or-miss and demands appropriate tuning.